# How to check if string exist in any part of the another string in python

Tags: python, string, match

I have a string str1 and it can exist in as a part in another sting as mentioned below.

str1="vikassharmabhardwaj"
comb_str="xxxvikasxddddsharma########bhardwaj"

I want to check if str1 exist in comb_str than it should return me output(vikas,sharma,bhardwaj)

Comment: The search words will have to be defined in some way, because although “vikass” exists in the string, so does “v”, “vi”, “vik” ... “kas” ... “ss”.  Do you see where I’m going with this?  Even if you incrementally expand the search string, Python does not intuitively know that you’re looking for “vikass” and not “kass”.

Answer (score 0):

Python can't know you are treating str1 as 3 different ones, expect if you explicitly define that. There are many ways to go about, I am proposing the following.

```
#! /usr/bin/python


str1="vikas"
str2 = 'sharma'
str3 = "bhardwaj" 

comb_str = "xxxvikasxddddsharma########bhardwaj"


def finderer(str1, str2, str3, comb_str):
    if str1 in comb_str and str2 in comb_str and str3 in comb_str: 
        return ( str1, str2, str3)


var = finderer(str1, str2, str3, comb_str)
print (var)
```

Comment: Thansk billy

actually i want to find continuous occurrence of search_text in the original_text.


original_text="test.vikas.ankur.priyansha.ashish.priyansha.test.vikas.ankur.ashish.priyansha.test."
search_text="vikas.ankur.ashish.priyansha"

in given example please consider each word as a sentence ,so in search_text i have multiple sentences and each sentence
can be found in multiple occurrence in original_text.i want to find out the span where search text sentence is found in continuous manner.